# What if I run tracert command while there is no connection to the DNS server?

Tags: dns, traceroute

What happens if I run the
`tracert x.x.x.x`
command while there is no connection to the DNS server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tracert` is a Windows executable which perform a traceroute to a destination given as argument. (The equivalent command on Linux or macOS is `traceroute`)

The destination you give as argument can be of two form:

- an IP address (IPv4 or IPv6)
- a DNS name, like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

If you use a DNS name, then this name must first be resolved by a DNS query. So the host on which you launch the command must be configured properly to resolve the name.

If you use an IP address (as implied in your question since `x.x.x.x` is usually a placeholder for an IPv4 address), obviously you don't need DNS resolution.

Comment: but what would happen I DNS server not responding?

Comment: if you use a DNS name and the DNS server doesn't respond.. Well it doesn't work and you get a message 'Unable to resolve target system name'
if you use an IP address, you don't need DNS so it works..

Answer (score 0):

`tracert` tries to resolve the traced gateway IP addresses "backwards" to host names (reverse DNS, PTR). If that fails due to DNS timeouts (DNS server configured but unreachable), it'll slow down the trace process.

On Windows, you could skip reverse DNS using the `-d` option.

Obviously, `tracert hostname` requires initial name resolution for `hostname`, not necessarily over DNS, depending on platform.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't make a difference if you use `tracert` or `ping` or any other application that would require an IP address down the line as its target.

As long as your system is not able to resolve a domain to its corresponding IP address - which it obviously doesn't, if it has no connection to a DNS server - how would it know where to send the message?

Keep the phone-book analogy in mind when using DNS: How would you know which number to dial, in order to reach Mr. Smith, without first looking it up in a phone-book?